# custom class marquee text restarts while changing another text view in a complex layout

Tags: android-layout, scroll, media-player, marquee, android-framelayout

I have own implementation of marquee class since the user can decide the marquee behavior (No scroll, scroll once, scroll repeat) for the text in my music app. The problem arise whenever user starts to play the songs since it continuously update **timer text (id:tv_playtime)** in the layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <FrameLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
   <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        <RelativeLayout

            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="onButtonHomeClick">
            <ImageView

                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                 />
            <ImageView

                android:layout_width="64.67dp"
                android:layout_height="25.33dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"

                android:background="@null"
                android:duplicateParentState="true"
                android:scaleType="fitStart"

                android:visibility="gone" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <!--home buttons-->
        <TextView

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="Media Player"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20dp" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_settings_btn_passenger"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <!--media player home-->
    <RelativeLayout

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        >
        <ImageView

            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

            android:tint="@color/white"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
        <ImageView

            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"

            />
        <ImageView

            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"

            />
        <ImageView

            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"

          />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <!-- playing indicator-->
    <RelativeLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="370dp"
            >
        <RelativeLayout

            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="240dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
            <ImageView

                android:layout_width="240dp"
                android:layout_height="240dp"
            />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="130dp"

            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
            <ImageView

                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"

                android:visibility="gone"/>
            <ImageView

                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="24dp"


                android:visibility="gone"/>
            <ImageView

                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="24dp"


                android:visibility="gone"/>
            <myClass.MarqueeTextView
                android:id="@+id/marqueetext1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:marqueeRepeatLimit="0"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="Song Name"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="24dp" />
            <myClass.MarqueeTextView
                android:id="@id/marqueetext2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/marqueetext1"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:marqueeRepeatLimit="0"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="Artist Name"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="18dp" />
            <myClass.MarqueeTextView
                android:id="@id/marqueetext3"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/marqueetext2"
                android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:marqueeRepeatLimit="0"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="Album Name"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_playtime"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/marqueetext2"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="00.00"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <!--media player tracks-->
    <RelativeLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="70dip"
        android:visibility="gone">
        <ImageView

            android:layout_width="30dip"
            android:layout_height="30dip"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="14dip"
             />
        <myClass.MarqueeTextView

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dip"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="14dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="0"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <!--mood-->
    <myClass.GestureView

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
         />
    <!--gestures-->
    <RelativeLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        >
        <RelativeLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="16dp">
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="28dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

            >
            <RelativeLayout

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="28dp">
                <TextView

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:text="00:00"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
                <TextView

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="7dip"
                    android:text="03:50"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="14dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
                <SeekBar

                    style="@style/seekBarMyStyle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="16dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                    android:maxHeight="2dp"
                    android:minHeight="2dp"
                    android:visibility="visible" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone">
        <RelativeLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="26dip"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
            <TextView

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:shadowColor="@color/text_shadow_color"
                android:shadowDx="2.5"
                android:shadowDy="2.5"
                android:shadowRadius="0.01"
                android:text="06:18"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
            <ImageView

                android:layout_width="26dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                 />
            <ImageView

                android:layout_width="26dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/iv_mp_battery"

                android:visibility="gone" />
            <ImageView

                android:layout_width="26dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"


                android:visibility="gone" />
            <ImageView

                android:layout_width="26dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"

                 />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="86dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/iv_mp_signal"
                 />
            <ImageView

                android:layout_width="86dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"

                 />
            <ImageView

                android:layout_width="86dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"

                />
            <ImageView

                android:layout_width="86dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"

                 />
            <ImageView

                android:layout_width="86dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"

                />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
   </RelativeLayout>
  <LinearLayout
    android:background="@color/darkbackgroundcoloralpha"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="176dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone" />
 </FrameLayout>
```

I want to  control the scrolling behavior of **marqueetext1** here, which is working fine when the song is paused (Since timer text field is not updating).

I've tried similar problems but none of them are working for me

- [TextView restarts Marquee when changing another TextView in same LinearLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11856875/textview-restarts-marquee-when-changing-another-textview-in-same-linearlayout)
- [Setting of TextView stops marquee scrolling of other TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7294779/setting-of-textview-stops-marquee-scrolling-of-other-textview)
- [Android, RelativeLayout restarts Marquee-TextView when changing ImageView in same RelativeLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203286/android-relativelayout-restarts-marquee-textview-when-changing-imageview-in-sam)

Note: Am using gestures for media player control (Next, previous, play, pause)

My assumption is its happening because of the layout since I've done a through debugging in custom Marquee class whose properties are not affecting the marquee restart here. I've override onFocusChanged, onWindowFocusChanged and isFocused methods in my derived Marquee class to make the Textview all focused.What am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My timer was overlapping on marquee text fields; so limiting the width of the timer text view solved the issue.

```
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_playtime"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/marqueetext2"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="00.00"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18dp" />
```